# Evolution hangs on startup

Tags: 21.04, evolution

I'm on Ubuntu 21.04 and I got recommendation to install 'Evolution' e-mail client. After installing it with 'sudo apt install evolution' and starting it from start menu or command line I don't see its window or anything going on, it just hangs. In command line I see these lines:

```
evolution 
bwrap: Can't mkdir parents for /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf: Read-only file system
```

Nothing goes on afterwards. I don't see any errors in *sudo dmesg | tail* or *less /var/log/syslog* . If I start it again I do get an error after few seconds that it is already running.

Where to look further for the error?

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: After running updates and updating to latest 21.10 Evolution works. Solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running updates and updating from Ubuntu 21.04 to latest 21.10 Evolution works. Solved.